# SWFAddress CHANGE event isn't dispatched

Tags: actionscript-3, swfaddress

I've successfully integrated SWFAddress deep linking on a site I'm working on. However I'm having a problem whereby SWFAddress CHANGE event isn't dispatched when you click an  anchor tag in the htmlText of a textField. The browsers address bar is successfully updated, just no CHANGE event.

How can I get it to dispatch in this scenario?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this one, for anyone else: I needed to use SWFObject to embed the Flash rather than jQuery.flash()